# CORS issue on chrome & firefox

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

The web API from IIS 7.5 are not responding for Chrome & Firefox.
I am getting the following error in chrome
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.xx.xx.xx:81' is therefore not allowed access

Firefox throw 401 unauthorized error.

Works perfectly on IE 11

Are there any additional setting required for these browsers?

Answer (score 1):

First install WebApi Cors NuGet Package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Then in your `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //other code
    }
}
```

This way you enable CORS header globally allowing cross-site requests from any domain. If you want to allow cross-site requests from only a single (or a list of) domain, then change the constructor parameters of `EnableCorsAttribute`:

```
new EnableCorsAttribute("http://alloweddomain.com", "*", "*");
```

You may also apply the `EnableCorsAttribute` on a Controller or Action basis.

More information on the official documentation: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks Federico, but as you see I have tried all the options. I am using aps.net web api 2.2. It works fine on IE but fails in Chrome & Firefox. Is there as sample reference that I can install & check?

Comment: I will check on link you provided & see I missed out something.

Comment: Enabling CORS in web.config has resolved the issue for Firefox & Chrome.http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Answer (score 0):

"A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain than the one which the first resource itself serves"
You can use a chrome addon to allow CORS:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: This will not work where the browser is used in controlled environment. Also this is not a generic fix. A server side fix will resolve the issue for Firefox also.

Comment: I tried setting IIS as mentioned below but that also did not worked.
http://webprojectsolution.blogspot.ca/2016/04/how-to-resolve-cors-issues-in-web-api.html

Comment: I have a similar problem, my application is built using Angular 7. I am making an ajax call to a BPMS server which works fine in IE but I have a CORS error in Chrome. However when I copy the ajax url to the Chrome browser I have all the data. Can anyone help?